# Upload multiple images with foreach

Tags: php, database, mysqli, upload

I searched the internet for days and i cant figure this out.

i have this code

```
    foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $value)
    {
        $name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
    }
```

I have a table in phpmyadmin with the name of img and two rows in it (url1) and (url2.

For example i submit 'pic1,jpg' and 'pic2.jpg' and i want to place 'pic1.jpg' in the row url1
and 'pic2.jpg' in the row url2

How would i do this, because i cant access the name of the images via the foreach loop.

For instance the variable $name has those two pictures in it, how would i echo the second picture?
without showing me the two pictures.

please help me i have been struggling for days now and grew a beard.

Comment: Simple: you don't store images in the database. there's very few usage cases that justify it, and the pain of in-db images vastly outweighs what minor advantages those usage cases gain.

Comment: I store the path in the db...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only uploading 2 images:

```
$images = $_FILES['images'];

foreach($images['name'] as $key => $value) {

     $file_name[$key] = $value;
     $file_tmp = $images['tmp_name'][$key];

     $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name); // images.jpg becomes images jpg
     $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext)); // We make the extension (jpg, gif etc.)
     // lowercase and separate it with "end" from images, which leaves us the extension

     $file_trim_name = rtrim($file_name, ".".$file_ext); // We remove the extension (.jpg)
     // from the image name

     $file_name_new = uniqid($file_trim_name . "-", true) . '.' . $file_ext; // Create a
     // "uniqid" (if you do not want to overwrite other images). We take the image name
     // and separate name and id by "-" and add the extension afterwards: $file_name_new = images-20302.jpg

     $file_destination = 'image/folder/location' . $file_name_new; // Choose file location

     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination); // Here we move images to their
     // location with the function "move_uploaded_file"

}

$url1 = $file_destination[0]; // Selecting first image
$url2 = $file_destination[1]; // Selecting second image

$query_images = "INSERT INTO images (url1, url2)

VALUES

('{$url1}', '{$url2}'";
```